# Backbone.Marionette - Replacing view but maintaining state

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, marionette

I have an Application, and two LayoutViews. Essentially a user interacts with one of these LayoutViews which is assigned to a region.

I would like to maintain the state of the view, so any input, any interaction with the view. However there is a button that a user can press to add a message. I would like this to be rendered in place of the previous view.

Currently, it always just renders the original layout, erasing any changes the user made.

```
    [.. setting up view "newMessageLayout" ..]

    App.newPostLayout = Page.layout = new newPostLayout;

    Page.layout.on('writeButtonClicked', function() {
        App.page.load('newMessage/addMessage');
        // (load essentially requires() the page)
    });
```

In pages/newMessage/addMessage.js:

```
    Page.layout = new addMessageLayoutView();

    Page.layout.on('onAddMessage', function() {

        // Process the new message
        // [....]

        // Show the write layout again
        App.uiInner.show(App.newPostLayout);
        // (uiInner is a region defined at the app level)

        // How do I show the previous version of the view???

    });

    // Renders the add post view
    App.uiInner.show(Page.layout, {preventDestroy: true});
```

How would I then render the saved state of the page in my `.show()` call. Is there a more standard way to do this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The standard way you should be doing this is by storing state in models and then when you render the layout again your state can easily be rendered again from the model.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - so, say for example this represents a new post. When I open the page and start interacting with it, I should create a new model somewhere? I don't want it bound to a collection just yet? Could I perhaps do `NewMessagePage.newMessageModel = new Backbone.Model.extend({...});` and check for its existence when the page is rendered?

Comment: Yeah, that is part of it. I don't know what your UI is so I can't say for certain, but whatever UI state is being reflected should be backed by a model already. So whenever you are rendering the page layout, you should already by passing it a model. Initially that model will probably have some kind of default state. Any changes through the UI should be pushed to the model. Then when you want to render that layout again, pass the same model back in and render the UI based on its state.

Comment: Thanks - really appreciate it - starting to find my way around this way of thinking now.